# How to get object reference in Core Data?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, entity-relationship, iphonecoredatarecipes

[image]

There is an entities where I am filling data from JSON, Say it is `Photographer` and `Photo`. Both have some data which I have filled using loop and managed `ObjectContex` ..

Like this,

```
NSMutableArray *ArrPhotographer= [[self.M3Arr objectForKey:@"LifeMag"]objectForKey:@"Photographer"];

for (int i = 0; i< ArrPhotographer.count; i++) {
 Photographer *  photographerObj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PhotographerData"
                                               inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    NSMutableDictionary *tpDict = [cleanerListArr objectAtIndex:i];
    photographerObj.cleanerName = [tpDict objectForKey:@"photographerName"];
}
```

Now I have done this for both Photographer and Photo Entity and as per this picture my Magazine entity is having data which are already existed in this table . And as shown I have made to one relation to both Photo and Photographer from Magazine .

Now Question is ,

If Photographer Name is already existed in the table , How can I connect it with Magazine Entity . I need the managed object Reference of that particular place .

(For Example , There are three photographer , Ron , Harry and Sunny now For Photo Cover1 I want name of Ron . then I need the Object Reference of Ron when I pre Populate it).

How to get this object Reference?

// **************** EDIT

I am getting the object is present ...but No how to fetch object and 2) how to give it to x and y stated above ?

```
I am using this code to saving the data in Magazine

    Magazine *magObj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Magazine"
                                                    inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];

    magObj .issueID=[NSNumber numberWithInt:1];
    magObj .photo= x;
    magObj .photographer = y;
```

#### Edit 2

```
   NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Cleaner"];
    [request setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"cleanerName = %@", @"Robin"]];
    [request setFetchLimit:1];
    NSUInteger count = [[self managedObjectContext] countForFetchRequest:request error:nil];
    if (count == NSNotFound){

        NSLog(@"ERROR FOund");
    }
    // some error occurred
    else if (count == 0){

        NSLog(@"no matching object");
    }
    // no matching object
    else{

        NSLog(@"Found Match");

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an `NSFetchRequest` to search the context for the appropriate object to connect to. The fetch request specifies the entity type to search for and you need to add an `NSPredicate` to filter the results to only the particular name that you're interested in.

Note that you could run a single fetch request with a list of names so that you only hit the data store for information once and then use the returned list during your object creation / connection loop.

If you're loading all of your data in one go, then you can create a dictionary which contains the managed object instances such that you can link to them without fetching.

Comment: Thanks for helping again :) .. well I have a question, Like tableview i can get any data from the indexpath.row/indexpath.coulmn.. in this entity , cant I get that perticuler object for somewhere ? will this [NSManagedObject objectID] help ?

Comment: No, the data store (MOC) is not indexed, it's a bag of contents. The index path is usable with an array or FRC (but only because that is a sorted extract). The `objectID` is the internal identifier. If you have the `objectID` already then you can directly request the associated object though...

Comment: So , As you have suggested ,  NSFetchRequest to search the context for the appropriate object to connect to ... This is the same Request we make for fetching data from any entity ? (For Example , I know I have to add the name "Ron" , Then should I get all the data of Photographer and check if "Ron" is there and then get that perticular object and its relation? is this correct or any other way ?)

Comment: Yes, but add the predicate to the fetch so the filtering is done in the data store. Then the results array you get should either be empty (no match, create a new item) or contain a single entry (match, connect relationship). If the array has more than one entry then you have duplicates...

Comment: Okay , then I think that to one relations from Magazine to photographer and photo are wrong . right ?

Comment: All relationships should have inverses. Most should be to-many. A photo can only have 1 photographer, but pretty much everything else can be many...

Comment: So you are suggesting , to-Many relationships from Magazine to Photo and Photographer also, Right ?

Comment: Yes, exactly. And the inverse, a photographer can be in many magazines, as can a photo.

Comment: See the Question I have edited ? the exact thing is how should I set X and Y ?

Comment: For a to-many your managed object subclass will have an `addXXX:` method that you can use

Comment: I want to set x = Jungle and y = Ron . If I am inserting them then it is creating the duplicate attribute to those perticuler entity [Both are already there in the pre populated data]

Comment: That's the purpose of the fetch, it verifies existence and then you can connect / create + connect

Comment: ok, so if it is existed then I only have to connect it , right ? I got your points about creating parts but how can I connect it , thy are already connected through toMany relations ..

Comment: Yes. Your model does not show to-many relationships. If you connect one end then the inverse relationship will be done automatically by Core Data

Comment: so it will be connected automatically right ?and this is out of the path question but I wanted to know what if I am making for only one magazine and one coverpage . So there will be only toOne relationship will be there . What should I do in that case?

Comment: that is your whole scenario. Always cover page with single photog + photo? Or this is just one case you want to cover? If to-one is suitable for your use case then fine, your code is ok, you just need a fetch

Comment: actually it is one to one case [in this case only I will definetely use your toMany case elsewhere in this project] . In that case My code is okay then problem is if I write x = Jungle and y = Ron then it is automatically adding a new data to both photographer and photo entity . It should connect to already existed entity there right ? it is not happening in current code written in Edit

Comment: Most likely photographer to cover needs to be to-many, because you could have multiple covers, but each cover just has 1 photo and each photo is only on 1 cover. New items are added when you call `insertNewObjectForEntityForName` - so don't call that till you have done a fetch and know if you need to do it or not

Comment: Ok , then if in case toOne case is there, 1) I have fetch all data from Photographer and photo entity Ron and jungle is there , so dont need to add new one 2)Now I need to add issueID but How should I connect Ron and Jungle (which I have found ) to this Magazine table ?

Comment: Exactly as you are now. Connecting the relations isn't giving you duplicates, it's the lack of fetching to verify existence that is causing you to create dupes

Comment: ok .. so I simply put x= @"Jungle" and y=@"Ron" and core data will take care of everything else . right ?

Comment: Not using strings, using the result of the fetch request(s) (the string name is part of the predicate) / newly created objects where required, and after you have created the inverse relationships

Comment: ok . well let me try it out in the code and will tell you what is happening , thanks so much wain . you are my core data guru :) .. kudos to you and up !!! :)

Comment: can you tell me the sample code about how to use the result of the fetch request ? or can you give me any link where it is there ? I am not able to do the as per your last instruction .

Comment: Likely don't use `countForFetchRequest`, because if you get a match you want to use the result. So, just execute the fetch and use the `count` of the returned array to check and then the `firstObject` if you got a match